# How to count json element in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get the object count and key counts for that json. I have tried to use count() function, it returns 2.

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);

echo count($data);
```

I want to get **2** for object count and **22** as each object's key count.

```
[
    {
       "name" : "EF",  
       "OrganizationID" : "1",  
       "name2" : "EF2",  
       "m2014" : "0",  
       "m2013" : "0",  
       "m2012" : "0",  
       "m2011" : "0",  
       "m2010" : "0",  
       "m2009" : "0",  
       "m2008" : "0",  
       "m2007" : "0",  
       "m2006" : "0",  
       "m2005" : "0",  
       "m2004" : "0",  
       "m2003" : "0",  
       "m2002" : "0",  
       "m2001" : "0", 
       "me" : "0",
       "a" : "0", 
       "a2" : "0", 
       "b" : "0", 
       "u" : "1"
   },{
       "name" : "IO",  
       "OrganizationID" : "2",  
       "name2" : "IOX",  
       "m2014" : "83",  
       "m2013" : "78",  
       "m2012" : "71",  
       "m2011" : "73",  
       "m2010" : "74",  
       "m2009" : "137",  
       "m2008" : "202",  
       "m2007" : "206",  
       "m2006" : "232",  
       "m2005" : "313",  
       "m2004" : "292",  
       "m2003" : "306",  
       "m2002" : "283",  
       "m2001" : "204", 
       "me" : "2339",
       "a" : "362", 
       "a2" : "0", 
       "b" : "1", 
       "u" : "1"
    }
]
```

Comment: You need to go deeper.

Comment: What if the object's have different sizes?

Comment: could you `var_dump` the variable `$data` so that we see what you have exactly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($json, true);

echo count($data);
echo count($data[0]);
```

or another one

```
echo count($data);
foreach($data as $o){
    echo count($o);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Subelement count:

```
echo sizeof($data, COUNT_RECURSIVE) - sizeof($data);
```

Element count:

```
echo sizeof($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "Object Count = ".$sizeof($data)."<br/>";

foreach($data as $key=>$arr)
{
   echo "Key - ".$key." Count = ".$sizeof($arr)."<br/>";
}
```